# Custom Search for a Custom List

Tags: 2013, javascript, search, custom-list, search-results

Searching is a beast to understand in SharePoint.  I am working in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise and created a custom list that has hundreds and hundreds of list items.  I cant use the search box for the custom list so I thought I could create a search option using search box/search results WP.  This works fine for the document libraries I have created this for but cant for the list. When I add the result source I created the added path does not produce results.  Is the search box/search results WP not the best thing for custom list?  I thought about using Key Filters Feature would work.  Do you think Key Filters is a better option? Should I create a Search Enterprise?

Comment: If your path is right and you cannot see the result, then try doing a full crawl and then check the result.

Comment: @harshalgite I tried crawl/reindex and still no results.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the list and the search query?

Comment: Using search box/search results WP is fine for searching custom list. Just make sure you are using the right query to fetch the results. [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/04/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013/) you will get the more idea about configuring search query in search results WP.